# How to show <Select > in sorted order

Tags: javascript, html

How can I sort the `<option>` elements of a `<select>` tag using JavaScript?

Here is the HTML I have:

```
<form action="example.asp">
<div>
<select size="3">
<option value="op2" >Option 2</option>
<option value="op1">Option 1</option>
<option value="op4">Option 4</option>
<option value="op3">Option 3</option>

</select>
</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
function sortlist() {
var lb = document.getElementById('mylist');
arrTexts = new Array();

for(i=0; i<lb.length; i++)  {
  arrTexts[i] = lb.options[i].text;
}

arrTexts.sort();

for(i=0; i<lb.length; i++)  {
  lb.options[i].text = arrTexts[i];
  lb.options[i].value = arrTexts[i];
}
}
</script>


<form action="#">
<select name=mylist id=mylist size=5>
<option value="Anton">Anton
<option value="Mike">Mike
<option value="Peter">Peter
<option value="Bill">Bill
<option value="Carl">Carl
</select>
<br>
<a href="javascript:sortlist()">sort</a>
</form>
```

Comment: i dont need to click and sort. its shoult be sort while its loading

Comment: than call this function in body load event

Comment: @Tree Then just call sortlist() from the <script> element.

Comment: That won't work if the names and values are different (as in the OP's question). See Yasir's answer for one which works with different values.

Answer (score 9):

If the value is different than the text, use the following function to sort both of them. This is just an updated version of above solution and will keep both the name and associated value.

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
function sortList() 
{ 
    var lb = document.getElementById('mylist'); 
    arrTexts = new Array(); 
    arrValues = new Array(); 
    arrOldTexts = new Array(); 

    for(i=0; i<lb.length; i++) 
    { 
        arrTexts[i] = lb.options[i].text; 
        arrValues[i] = lb.options[i].value; 
        arrOldTexts[i] = lb.options[i].text; 
    } 

    arrTexts.sort(); 

    for(i=0; i<lb.length; i++) 
    { 
        lb.options[i].text = arrTexts[i]; 
        for(j=0; j<lb.length; j++) 
        { 
            if (arrTexts[i] == arrOldTexts[j]) 
            { 
                lb.options[i].value = arrValues[j]; 
                j = lb.length; 
            } 
        } 
    } 
}
</script>
```

Comment: Prefer the solution of @jeffpar below, because it doesn't need the helper array with extra loops at the end. Also that solution is shorter.

Answer (score 4):

You should think about it on the pre html-creation level. If you are generating them from some kind of list or by dynamic page mechanism then sort them before you generate your option elements - thats the clearest way ;)

Comment: It's not always the best way of doing it however. Sometimes you just have a need to sort an html list. For example, I just had a customer give me a list of items to put in an html list. I would prefer to keep them in the same order as the customer gave me (for ease of maintenance), but have them sorted when displayed to the user.

Answer (score 1):

A simpler solution, building on Yasir Al-Agl's answer:

```
function sortList() 
{ 
    var lb = document.getElementById('mylist'); 
    arr = new Array(); 

    for(i = 0; i < lb.length; i++) { 
        arr[i] = lb.options[i]; 
    } 

    arr.sort(function(a,b) {
        return (a.text > b.text)? 1 : ((a.text < b.text)? -1 : 0);
    });  // or use localeCompare() if you prefer

    for(i = 0; i < lb.length; i++) { 
        lb.options[i] = arr[i];
    }
}
```

In short, you need only one Array, the elements of which are simply references to the original "options" Objects.  The sort() function also has the freedom to choose which option property to sort on (ie, the text property, the value property, etc).

Don't forget, however, that the "selectedIndex" property of the "select" control may no longer be correct after the sort.

Answer (score 1):

This function works as in the last answer, but also keeps the selection of  item

```
// Sorts all entries of a select item (= dropdown) by their visible name, keeping the internal values and the selection
function sortSelectEntries(selItem) {
    let formerSel = selItem.value;
    let count = selItem.length;
    let options = new Array();
    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++)
        options[i] = selItem.options[i];
    options.sort((e1, e2) => e1.text > e2.text ? 1 : (e1.text < e2.text ? -1 : 0));
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
        selItem.options[i] = options[i];
    selItem.value = formerSel; // restore selection
}
```